# Content inside ConstraintLayout does not scroll when "adjustPan" soft input mode is set

Tags: android, android-layout, android-softkeyboard, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I tried to replace the `ScrollView` with the `NestedScrollView` and wrap all Views in the `CoordinatorLayout`, but that did not help.
Without `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` it works, but I do not like how layout changes when the keyboard is opened; I want the keyboard to overlap layout, rather than squeeze it.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**activity_login.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ImageView_nyatrix_logo"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/til_login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_logo_big" />

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/til_password"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/ImageView_nyatrix_logo">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText_login"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="login/phone/email" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/til_homeServer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_login">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText_password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="password" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_homeServer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/til_identityServer"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_password">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText_homeServer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="homeserver"
                android:text="https://matrix.org"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_identityServer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/Button_login"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_homeServer">

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/EditText_identityServer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="identity server"
                android:text="https://vector.im" />
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/Button_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Login"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/til_identityServer" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="ru.sabernyan.nyatrix">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:fullBackupContent="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning"
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: without this line your    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" layout change or not.

Comment: @AndroidTeam yep, my layout scrolls as it should. Or are you talking about size and distance changes between Views?